# Microsoft Command Prompt deleting every file with same name pattern

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I want to delete all the eclipse files which have different extensions. Is there any cmd command for deleting every file with the same name pattern?

I wrote this command.

> C:>del eclipse /a /s

which I found from the Internet but It did not work?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a *wildcard*. A wildcard can be either `*` meaning *any number of characters*, or `?` meaning *any single character*.

Since you are looking for files named *eclipse* with any extension, this would be:

```
del /a /s eclipse.*
```

This will delete eclipse.txt, eclipse.doc, eclipse, etcetera.